# Why are bears in yaoi animes?

Tags: tropes

In Yaoi I have fairly noticed a highly recurring thing which is **Bears**. In particular I am aiming this at Yaoi's such as Sekai Ichi Hatsukoi and Junjou Romantica.

Examples:

[image]
[image] [image]

So my question is **what is the relationship between the re-occurring bears seen in Yaoi's such as Sekai Ichi Hatsukoi and Junjou Romantica** and **are bears related to homosexuals in yaoi?** and where did the idea of **bears** come from? **Why bears?**

Comment: Perhaps some sort of reference to [Pedobear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedobear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was surprised that my question didn't really get that much interest really, but I think I may know why bears appear in Yaoi's and quite frequently. I think this is in relation to [gay culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_%28gay_culture%29).....

> In male bisexual and gay culture, a *Bear* is a **large, hairy man who projects an image of rugged masculinity. Bears are one of many LGBT communities** with events, codes, and a culture-specific identity.

It obviously does not mean an actual bear, but in Yaoi's I think it showcases or quite frequently shows/depicts bears as to relate to (well obviously) homosexuals or gays and the definition for yaoi is....

> Yaoi, also known as Boys' Love, is a Japanese genre of fictional media **focusing on homoerotic romantic or sexual relationships between male characters**

Also see [here](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130911103627AAVwei7).

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but sometimes a member of a gay couple can be called a [Bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_%28gay_culture%29). This man is usually rugged and macho, and usually hairy.

Wikipedia describes a **Teddy** Bear as:

> A fully hairy Bear. Chest, back, beard, everything is hairy

So perhaps this is a reference to that, seeing as you mention it occurs significantly often in yaoi?

Comment: macho... hairy... Bara... ( ._.)

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the mangaka, Nakamura Shungiku, likes to show link between her two works, Junjou Romantica and Sekai-ichi Hatsukoi. In Junjou Romantica, bears have debuted the work as "Suzuki-san" and hence maybe she likes to show links using the bear and bunny mascots